# Android Compose: Type is defined multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

and thanks in advance for any help.

I'm new to Android development, so apologies if my question is stupid or duplicate.

I'm using jetpack compose on Android Studio `4.2.0-alpha12` and Gradle version `6.6.1`. I'm getting the error when I build the app

```
Type com.example.athis.model.course.Coordinate-$$ExternalSynthetic1 is defined multiple times: /Users/noahtatko/AndroidStudioProjects/golf_score_android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/debug/out/com/example/athis/model/course/Coordinate.dex, /Users/noahtatko/AndroidStudioProjects/golf_score_android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/debug/out/com/example/athis/model/course/Hole.dex
```

The kotlin files (not the `.dex` files) are as follows:

```kotlin
// Hole.kt
package com.example.athis.model.course

import androidx.compose.runtime.Immutable

@Immutable
data class Hole(
    val id: Long,
    val hole: Long,
    val yards: Long,
    val handicap: Int,
    val par: Int,
    val coordinates: Coordinate
)
```

```kotlin
// Coordinate.kt
package com.example.athis.model.course

import androidx.compose.runtime.Immutable

@Immutable
data class Coordinate(
    val id: Long,
    val lat: Double,
    val long: Double
)
```

I've tried switching my gradle version, since that seems to be the normal fix, but because I'm using compose, I'm limited to releases after 6.6.1, none of which have helped.

One odd thing that may factor in: even though I'm on a Mac, I have a `gradlew.bat` file, and `./gradlew build` does not work. Is there a way to regenerate these? I've tried deleting them, but then the app fails to run at all, not just build failures.

Comment: I commented out the `val coordinates: Coordinate` and still got the same error, so it shouldn't be an issue of circular deps or anything.

Comment: The `gradlew.bat` file won't work on Man, only Windows. About the main problem, have you tried running "Clean project"?

Comment: Yeah, didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the main issue was with the version of compose I was using `1.0.0-alpha3`. Jumping to `1.0.0-alpha4` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade Gradle from 6.8-rc3 to 6.8-rc1 to get the error you posted above to go away.